# Boxplot width in ggplot with cross classified groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making boxplots with ggplot with data that is classified by 2 factor variables.  I'd like to have the box sizes reflect sample size via `varwidth = TRUE` but when I do this the boxes overlap.

1) Some sample data with a 3 x 2 structure

```
data <- data.frame(group1= sample(c("A","B","C"),100, replace = TRUE),group2= sample(c("D","E"),100, replace = TRUE) ,response = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

2) Default boxplots: ggplot without variable width

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(y = response, x = group1, color = group2)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

I like how the first level of grouping is shown.
Now I try to add variable widths...

3) ...and What I get when `varwidth = TRUE`

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(y = response, x = group1, color = group2)) + geom_boxplot(varwidth = T)
```

[image]

This overlap seems to occur whether I use `color = group2` or `group = group2` in both the main call to `ggplot` and in the `geom_boxplot` statement.  Fussing with `position_dodge` doesn't seem to help either.

4) A solution I don't like visually is to make unique factors by combining my group1 and group2

```
data$grp.comb <- paste(data$group1, data$group2)

ggplot(data = data, aes(y = response, x = grp.comb, color = group2)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

I prefer having things grouped to reflect the cross classification

5) The way forward: 
I'd like to either a)figure out how to either make  `varwidth = TRUE` not cause the boxes to overlap or b)manually adjusted the space between the combined groups so that boxes within the 1st level of grouping are closer together.

Comment: This is not a solution to the stated problem, but I would add that having the overlapping boxes is probably better from a interpretation perspective as you can accurately compare widths, vs having to measure it out in your head. To see both plots, I would use the alpha argument here instead `ggplot(data = data, aes(y = response, x = group1, color = group2)) + 
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = T, alpha = 0.5)`

Comment: See my solution below

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem can be solved best by using `facet_wrap`.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    data <- data.frame(group1= sample(c("A","B","C"),100, replace = TRUE), group2= 
    sample(c("D","E"),100, replace = TRUE) ,response = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1))

    ggplot(data = data, aes(y = response, x = group2, color = group2)) + 
      geom_boxplot(varwidth = TRUE) +
      facet_wrap(~group1)
```

Which gives:
[image]

Comment: Not exactly how I wanted it -I wanted to avoid facets-, but yes, it works. Thank you! I will wait a little bit to see if somebody can do the graph in only one facet. Otherwise, the bounty will be yours.

Answer (score 1):

A recent update to ggplot2 makes it so that the code provided by @N Brouwer in (3) works as expected:

```
# library(devtools)
# install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")

packageVersion("ggplot2") # works with v2.2.1.9000
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(group1= sample(c("A","B","C"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                   group2= sample(c("D","E"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                   response = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1))

ggplot(data = data, aes(y = response, x = group1, color = group2)) + 
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = T)
```

(I'm a new user and can't post images inline)
[fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IlnI.png)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered here [ggplot increase distance between boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342616/ggplot-increase-distance-between-boxplots)

The answer involves using the `position = position_dodge()` argument of `geom_boxplot()`.

For your example:

```
data <- data.frame(group1= sample(c("A","B","C"),100, replace = TRUE),  group2= 
                 sample(c("D","E"),100, replace = TRUE) ,response = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1))

ggplot(data = data, aes(y = response, x = group1, color = group2)) + 
 geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(1))
```

[image]