# ggplot increase distance between boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

How can I avoid attached box-plots? Thank you

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(time), y=val, fill=ID))+
geom_boxplot()+
scale_fill_manual(values=c(WT="goldenrod3", KO="steelblue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `position_dodge`, the `width` argument can help with spacing

```
mtcars$sep <- 1:2  # a factor

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(carb), y=mpg, fill=factor(sep))) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0.8))
```